# Create composite index using concat in mysql

Tags: mysql, grouping, concatenation

Using the following command I am being able to get the `create index` command,

```
SELECT CONCAT ('
create index ',index_name,' on ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' (',COLUMN_NAME,');'  
) FROM 
inf_schema.STATS WHERE 
table_schema='employee' AND 
table_name='FILESPROC' AND 
index_name NOT LIKE 'PRIMARY' ;
```

I get the following output:

```
create index FILENAMEPROCID on employee.FILESPROCESSED (PROCID);
create index FILENAMEPROCID on employee.FILESPROCESSED (FILENAME);
create index NENDDATEDataName on employee.FILESPROCESSED (DSN);
create index NENDDATEDataName on employee.FILESPROCESSED (ENDDATE);
create index NENDDATEDataName on employee.FILESPROCESSED (DataName);
create index DSN on employee.FILESPROCESSED (DSN);
create index ENDDATE on employee.FILESPROCESSED (ENDDATE);
```

However, I need the output in the following manner:

```
create index FILENAMEPROCID on employee.FILESPROCESSED (PROCID, FILENAME);
create index NENDDATEDataName on employee.FILESPROCESSED (DSN, ENDDATE, DataName);
create index DSN on employee.FILESPROCESSED (DSN);
create index ENDDATE on employee.FILESPROCESSED (ENDDATE);
```

so that I am able to create composite indexes. How am I to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` on selected `COLUMN_NAME` that have same `INDEX_NAME`.

```
SELECT 
        CONCAT (
          'create index ', index_name, ' on ', table_schema, '.', table_name, 
          ' ( ', GROUP_CONCAT( COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ' ), ' );'  
        ) indexes_scripts
  FROM 
        inf_schema.STATS 
 WHERE 
        table_schema='employee' 
   AND  table_name='FILESPROC'
   AND  index_name NOT LIKE 'PRIMARY' 
 GROUP BY index_name
```

Comment: This groups up all the column names into one `create index` command. What i need is, group the `create index` for the same index name, and if the index name are different then make separate `create index` for each one of them

Comment: ok adding a group by to the end of the query solved the issue. thanks a ton.. :)

Comment: Yes. That part I missed to include. Included and corrected minor error.